# invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/local/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 598

Tags: linux, perl

When I try send an email using `Net::SMTP::TLS` from perl script I am getting below:

> invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/local/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 598

OS:Linux

You know what the problem is and what I have to do to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Provide some more description/code example and what you've checked so far.

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53065/102866 & http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249424/102866

Answer (score 2):

Net::SMTP::TLS is not maintained since 10 years and it is broken in that it causes exactly the error you describe. If you insist of using this broken module you need to fix it. Change the [code in line 182](https://metacpan.org/source/AWESTHOLM/Net-SMTP-TLS-0.12/lib/Net/SMTP/TLS.pm#L182) to remove the invalid setting of SSL_version:

```
    if(not IO::Socket::SSL::socket_to_SSL($me->{sock},
-        SSL_version     =>   "SSLv3 TLSv1")){
+        )){
             croak "Couldn't start TLS: ".IO::Socket::SSL::errstr."\n";
    }
```

Instead of using the broken and unmaintained Net::SMTP::TLS or its successor but again unmaintained [Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained) I suggest you use the latest version of [Net::SMTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP) which has built in support for both kinds of SMTP+SSL and for IPv6 too. It comes already by default with newer Perl versions.

If using a new Net::SMTP  is not possible you might use [Net::SSLGlue::SMTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLGlue::SMTP) which monkey patches older Net::SMTP version to add SSL support. And there is also [Net::SMTPS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTPS) which provides a similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize as I had just fixed my problem (Thanks to the contributors above)

1. Open [Perl_dir]/site/lib/Net/SMTP/TLS.pm
2. Look for line 182, which looks like
   ***if(not IO::Socket::SSL::socket_to_SSL($me->{sock}, SSL_version=>"SSLv3 TLSv1")){***
3. Changed to line below by removing "SSL_version=>"SSLv3 TLSv1"
   ***if(not IO::Socket::SSL::socket_to_SSL($me->{sock})){***
4. Save [Perl_dir]/site/lib/Net/SMTP/TLS.pm

Other ref URL:
http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,143156.msg1223280.html#msg1223280